# REGEX for search specific keywords along with regex for time search

Tags: java, regex

I have a java string which contains time (am|pm format) along with specific keywords like SET or UNSET and few other irrelevant words.
for example set time as 10:30 am
or UNSET time as 10:30 pm.

I already have regex for time as

```
regex_am_pm = "(?:\\s{1,2}[1-9]|\\s{1,2}0[1-9]|\\s{1,2}1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9]\\s{0,2}(?:am|pm|AM|PM)";.
```

how do I include regex to check for initials SET or UNSET before time REGEX.

please help.

```
regex_am_pm = "(SET|UNSET)(?:\\s{1,2}[1-9]|\\s{1,2}0[1-9]|\\s{1,2}1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9]\\s{0,2}(?:am|pm|AM|PM)";
```

I want to search for set or unset proceeded with time regex. anything allowed in between

**Output Expected**

```
String passed = "hey Set clock to 10:30 PM"
if SET found before time regex
outPut if(SetMethod(String time))
       else(UNSetMethod(String time))
```

Comment: It would greatly help your question to add sample text which you are trying to match, covering all edge cases which the regex would need to capture.

Comment: I would not use regex this way.  Parse your input and deal with it in code.  Your requirement sounds like a simple grammar that is beyond the intent of regex.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I added the expected out put, if I find SET keyword before time regex then call SETMethod or else unset method

Comment: Prepend your pattern with `(UN)?SET.*?` and once you get a match use `if(matcher.group(1) != null) { SETMethod; } else{ UNSETmdthod; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should think that you would want to validate the incoming string so as to ensure it actually contains the words SET or UNSET (regardless of letter case), the word **time** is within the string so as to confirm what the SET is for, and the fact that a time is also contained within the string.

String rules:

- Must contain either the word **SET** or **UNSET** (regardless of letter
  case). Either must be words upon their own rather than part of another word;
- Must contain the word **time** (regardless of letter case) *somewhere
  after* the word **SET** or **UNSET** so as to eliminate some
  ambiguity;
- Must contain a time in the format **hh:mm** (12 hour time) or
  **HH:mm** (24 hour time). **AM** or **PM** is optional and letter case is irrelevant. The actual time must be placed *somewhere after*
  the word **time** again, so as to eliminate some ambiguity.

**Some code you can try:**

```
// The Regular Expression (RegEx) we are going to use...
String regEx = "(?i)(\\bSET\\b|\\bUNSET\\b)(.*?\\btime\\b.*?)?(\\d{2}\\:\\d{2}(\\s+)?(am|pm)?)";

String incomingString = "set time as 10:30 am";

String setType = "NONE AVAILABLE!"; // Default
String setTime = "NONE AVAILABLE!"; // Default
String timeFormat = "";             // Default

// Does the incoming String meet our requirements?
if (incomingString.trim().matches(regEx)) {
    // Yes it does...
    System.out.println("String contains valid content.");

    // Get the required information from the input String...
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(regEx);
    Matcher m = r.matcher(incomingString);
    if (m.find()) {
        setType = m.group(1).toUpperCase();
        setTime = m.group(3).toUpperCase();
    }

    // Is the time Valid
    timeFormat = validateTime(setTime); // see validateTime() method
    if (timeFormat.equals("NONE")) {
        // Reset to defaults
        setType = "NONE AVAILABLE!";
        setTime = "NONE AVAILABLE!";
    }
}
// Display the findings...
System.out.println("Set Type: " + setType);
System.out.println("Time:     " + setTime + " (in " + timeFormat + ")");
```

The **validateTime()** method:

```
/**
 * If valid this method will return a string indicating the Time Format 
 * otherwise it will return the uppercase word string: "NONE".<br>
 * 
 * @param time (String) The time to validate in HH:mm or hh:mm (am/pm).<br>
 * 
 * @return (String) Either "24 Hour Format", "12 Hour Format", or "NONE" if 
 * validation fails.
 */
public static String validateTime(String time) {
    String fmt = "NONE";
    // 12 Hour Time...
    if (time.matches("(1[012]|[1-9]):[0-5][0-9](\\s)?(?i)(am|pm)")) {
        fmt = "12 Hour Format";
    }        
    // 24 Hour Time...
    else if (time.matches("([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]")) {
        fmt = "24 Hour Format";
    }
    return fmt;
}
```

**The Regular Expression Explanation:**

```
(?i)(\\bSET\\b|\\bUNSET\\b)(.*?\\btime\\b.*?)?(\d{2}\\:\\d{2}(\\s+)?(am|pm)?)

(?i)
match the remainder of the pattern with the following effective flags: gmi
i modifier: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of [a-zA-Z])

1st Capturing Group:   (\\bSET\\b|\\bUNSET\\b)
1st Alternative:  \\bSET\\b
\\b assert position at a word boundary: (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)
SET matches the characters SET literally (case insensitive)
\\b assert position at a word boundary: (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)

2nd Alternative:  \\bUNSET\\b
\\b assert position at a word boundary: (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)
UNSET matches the characters UNSET literally (case insensitive)
\\b assert position at a word boundary: (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)

2nd Capturing Group:   (.*?\\btime\\b.*?)?
? Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
.*?  matches any character (except for line terminators)
*? Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
\\b assert position at a word boundary: (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)
time matches the characters time literally (case insensitive)
\\b assert position at a word boundary: (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)
.*?  matches any character (except for line terminators)

3rd Capturing Group:  (\\d{2}\\:\\d{2}(\\s+)?(am|pm)?)
\\d{2}  matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
{2} Quantifier — Matches exactly 2 times 
\\: matches the character : literally (case insensitive)
\\d{2}  matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
{2} Quantifier — Matches exactly 2 times 

4th Capturing Group:   (\\s+)?
? Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\s+  matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])

5th Capturing Group:   (am|pm)?
? Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
1st Alternative:   am
am matches the characters am literally (case insensitive)
2nd Alternative:  pm
pm matches the characters pm literally (case insensitive)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use any NLP parsers ? 
Several pieces of advice :

1. You should cut the text in sentences before. I suppose you do not want your program to catch this case :

> I do not need to buy a a set  of three earings for my daughter any
>   more. I shall sleep until 10:30 PM.

Here you have ambiguity, too (set here means other thing than you mean). And the meaning you need is in one sentence/phrase only.

2. Within the phrase/sentence, you may do :

```java
String regex_am_pm = "(\\s((UN)?SET)\\s(.*?)[1-2]\\d:[0-5]\\d)\\s(am|pm|AM|PM)";
```

By the way, there is a problem if you have this text :

> I need to UNSET my application and SET the clock to 10:30 AM.

If you want to test the regex in another environement than Java, use \ at the place of \ :

```
(\s((UN)?SET)\s(.*?)[1-2]\d:[0-5]\d)\s(am|pm|AM|PM)
```

Comment: I can guide user to be specific with text format, but
"(\\s((UN)?SET)\\s(.*?)[1-2]\\d:[0-5]\\d)\\s(am|pm|AM|PM)"; this is nt working form me,
I tested it at regex101,

Comment: I tested it on regex101 too and it works for the sentence :  "Hi SET this to 10:30 AM". You must replace \\ by \ in it. The regex I provided has \\ as required in Java. Do you always have SET and UNSET in upper case?